# Is there a way to make [incr Tcl] classes friends?

Tags: oop, tcl, private, friend, incr-tcl

Is there a way to obtain a friendship between classes in [incr Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/man/itcl3.1/class.n.html)?

Consider the code below.

```
package require Itcl

::itcl::class A {
   private {
      proc f { } {
         puts "==== A::f"
      }
   }
}

::itcl::class B {
   public {
      proc g { } {
         puts "==== want to be able to call A::f"
      }
   }
}
```

I want `A::f` to be invisible outside `A` bur functions of `B`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itcl doesn't provide friends.

You can hack around this by constructing a call using [`namespace inscope`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M14), like so:

```
namespace inscope A {A::f}
```